# Cannot slice pandas dataframe with integer label

Tags: pandas

Consider the following code

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "timestamp": [1616131200, 1616131500, 1616131800, 1616132100],  
    "topic": ["A", "A", "B", "B"],
    "message_id": [1, 2, 3, 4]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(["topic", "timestamp"])
relevant_df = df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 12:]]
```

Running the script results in the error

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on Index with these indexers [12] of type int
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong. If I convert the integer label to a string, the error disappears.

```
relevant_df = df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, "12":]]
```

This seems extremely bizzarre. If I use the correct label type, the slice fails, but if I use the wrong type, the slice succeeds.

It seems the issue only arises when using a multi-index. Using a single index of "timestamp" allows for indexing by the integer label.

Comment: I'd do `df.query('timestamp >= 1616131500')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: As @e-motta mentioned in the comment, this is by design. Here is the content from his link below for convenience.

> https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers
>
> You can slice a MultiIndex
> ...
> You should specify all axes in the .loc specifier, meaning the indexer
> for the index and for the columns. There are some ambiguous cases
> where the passed indexer could be misinterpreted as indexing both
> axes, rather than into say the MultiIndex for the rows.
>
> You should do this:
>
> `df.loc[(slice("A1", "A3"), ...), :]  # noqa: E999`
>
> You should not do
> this:
>
> `df.loc[(slice("A1", "A3"), ...)]  # noqa: E999`

Original Answer:

I have found a work-around. If I explicitly select all columns, the slice succeeds. For example

```
relevant_df = df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 1616131500:], :]
```

(note the trailing `,:]` term.)

Comment: It's not exactly a workaround. If you don't explicitly select the columns, Pandas will interpret the code in your question as indexing both axes. See the first warning in the documentation about multiindex slicing: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers